# Appears to be valid C, but with error: "Expected identifier or '('"

Tags: c, macos, gcc

So I am getting an error in the header file.
gcc is telling me that the error is at the 't' in the following line.

```
char* typeof(char*);
```

The corresponding code in the corresponding .c file is as follows.

```
char* typeof(char* word) {
  int q = -1;
  do {
    char c = word[++q];
  } while (c);
  char* new = !q ? 0 : malloc(sizeof(char) * q);
  while (q > 0) {
    new[--q] = word[q] >= 'A' && word[q] <= 'Z' ? word[q] - 'A' : word[q] - 'a';
  }
  return new;
}
```

What other information do you guys need to know?

I am using a Mac, writing this code using vim within Terminal, and compiling using Mac's gcc.

```
fvfs-MacBook-Pro:src fvf$ which vi
/usr/bin/vi
fvfs-MacBook-Pro:src fvf$ ll /usr/bin/vi
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  3 Oct  5 11:33 /usr/bin/vi@ -> vim
fvfs-MacBook-Pro:src fvf$ ll /usr/bin/vim
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1745984 Oct 19 05:38 /usr/bin/vim*
fvfs-MacBook-Pro:src fvf$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
fvfs-MacBook-Pro:src fvf$ ll /usr/bin/gcc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18240 Oct 19 05:11 /usr/bin/gcc*
```

("ll" at the command line is an alias for "ls -l")

[image: My IDE did not tell me it was a reserved word.]

Comment: `typeof` is a reserved word in C (rather: a gcc extension) - don't try and name a function like that.

Comment: It typically is color highlighted in the IDE as well, giving a strong hint.

Comment: Try to compile as standard C with `-std=c11`.

Comment: @Eiko Thanks for your unhelpful comment.  Look at the picture I posted.

Comment: @fvf Sorry for wasting my time on this, I should have known your screenshot an hour before you posted it. By the way, Xcode highlights this clearly as a keyword for me, and as you mentioned OS X, I think that was a reasonable guess.

Comment: @fvf yes, i got that when I tried to run the code. Thanks for enlightening me, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The proximate cause of the error (with the terrible error message) is you've used a reserved word (`typeof`) as your function name.

This error masks two more:

```
do {
  char c = word[++q];
} while (c);
```

`c` is not at scope for the `while` here.

```
char* new = !q ? 0 : malloc(sizeof(char) * q);
```

`sizeof(char)` is always 1 and thus superfluous, and you're not checking the return value of `malloc` for errors.

Comment: @fvf, do you really have to reimplement `strlen`?

Answer (score 0):

This fails since `typeof` is a reserved word in [the GCC compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html), and thus you can't use it as the name of a function.

Just pick another name, and you should be fine.

Also, using `new` in C is fine but that's a C++ keyword which might confuse some environments/editors (such as Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting).

Finally, you should use `strlen()` rather than looping on your own, much less confusing. And scaling by `sizeof (char)` is silly in my opinion, it's always 1, but some people feel it adds some documentationary<sup>1</sup> value.

<sup>1</sup> That's a word, since I just used it.